# Word and Char ngram with different ngram range on TFIDFVectorizer Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining, tf-idf, grid-search

I'm trying to run a Pipeline with 3 to 5 char n-grams and 1 to 2 word n-grams, with Pipeline and GridSearch, but im getting some errors. Here the full code:

```
def prediction(dataFrame):
     allText = []
     for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows():
        allText.append(res)

    pipeline = Pipeline([
          ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2,analyzer="char",sublinear_tf=True,max_df=0.01,ngram_range=(3,5))),
          ('vec', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2,sublinear_tf=True,analyzer="word",max_df=0.01,ngram_range=(1,2))),
          ('clf', LinearSVC()),
     ])
     parameters = [{
          'clf__C': [0.1, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 5]
     }]
     grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters,scoring="accuracy",cv=5)
     grid_search.fit(allText,dataFrame.gender)
     print("Best parameter (CV score=%0.3f):" % grid_search.best_score_)
```

I'm getting some erors like "AttributeError: lower not found" on FeatureExtraction, besides all text seems correct.

What is wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Pipeline`, you chain two `TfidfVectorizer` vectorizers so after the first vectorizer you get *numerical* features, which are then passed into the second one. But your goal is to *concatenate* two different `TfidfVectorizer` feature matrices. Pipelines apply transformers (and a final estimator if given) sequentially, while [`FeatureUnion`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) runs all the transformers separately and concatenates the results into a single feature space.

Solution:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

# Replace your pipeline with this:
char_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(3, 5))
word_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 2))
tfidf = FeatureUnion([('char', char_tfidf), ('word', word_tfidf)])
pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', tfidf), ('clf', LinearSVC())])
```